# How to detect clipboard text changes?

Tags: delphi, clipboard, delphi-xe7

How can my application receive a notification when the clipboard text changes?

**For example:**

I would to enable/disable a paste button and setting its `Hint` property in order to display the clipboard's text (like `'Paste "%s"'`)

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TMyPasteForm = class(TForm)
    MyPasteButton: TButton;
    MyEdit: TEdit;
    procedure MyPasteButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure SyncMyPasteButton();
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  MyPasteForm: TMyPasteForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  Clipbrd;

procedure TMyPasteForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyPasteButton.ShowHint := True;
end;

procedure TMyPasteForm.MyPasteButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyEdit.Text := Clipboard.AsText;
end;

procedure TMyPasteForm.SyncMyPasteButton();
begin
  MyPasteButton.Enabled := Length(Clipboard.AsText) > 0;
  MyPasteButton.Hint := Format('Paste "%s"', [Clipboard.AsText]);
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found an interesting [PDF arcticle](https://github.com/delphidabbler/articles/blob/master/article-9.pdf) and edited my example accordingly with the *"Using the clipboard listener API"* section of the article:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TMyPasteForm = class(TForm)
    MyPasteButton: TButton;
    MyEdit: TEdit;
    procedure MyPasteButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure SyncMyPasteButton();
    procedure WMClipboardUpdate(var Msg : TMessage); message WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE;
  protected
    procedure CreateWnd(); override;
    procedure DestroyWnd(); override;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  MyPasteForm: TMyPasteForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  Clipbrd;

procedure TMyPasteForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyPasteButton.ShowHint := True;

  SyncMyPasteButton();
end;

procedure TMyPasteForm.CreateWnd();
begin
  inherited;
  //making sure OS notify this window when clipboard content changes
  AddClipboardFormatListener(Handle);
end;

procedure TMyPasteForm.DestroyWnd();
begin
  //remove the clipboard listener
  RemoveClipboardFormatListener(Handle);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyPasteForm.MyPasteButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyEdit.Text := Clipboard.AsText;
end;

procedure TMyPasteForm.SyncMyPasteButton();
begin
  MyPasteButton.Enabled := IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_TEXT);

  if(MyPasteButton.Enabled) then
    MyPasteButton.Hint := Format('Paste "%s"', [Clipboard.AsText])
  else
    MyPasteButton.Hint := '';
end;

procedure TMyPasteForm.WMClipboardUpdate(var Msg : TMessage);
begin
  //the clipboard content is changed!
  SyncMyPasteButton();
end;

end.
```

**Note:**

- It works for *Windows Vista* and later.
- If you need to support *Windows XP* and earlier you must use a clipboard viewer approach (See the *"Using the clipboard viewer chain"* section of the previously mentioned [article](https://github.com/delphidabbler/articles/blob/master/article-9.pdf). See also [SetClipboardViewer()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setclipboardviewer) and [Monitoring Clipboard Contents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard#monitoring-clipboard-contents))

Comment: A Form’s `Handle` may change during its lifetime, so it would be better to override the Form’s virtual `CreateWnd()`/`DestroyWnd()` or `CreateWindowHandle()`/`DestroyWindowHandle()` methods to perform the (de)registration of the clipboard listener. Also, if you need to support XP and earlier, use [`SetClipboardViewer()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setclipboardviewer) instead of `AddClipboardFormatListener()`. See [Monitoring Clipboard Contents](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard#monitoring-clipboard-contents).

Comment: Your solution reacts to **every** change, not just text. There's no guarantee that the clipboard content can always be converted to text - consider [IsClipboardFormatAvailable()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-isclipboardformatavailable) before you assume the content is text at all - have you never copy/pasted pictures or files in your life?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thanks for your suggestions. I've updated the answer by using `CreateWnd`/`DestroyWnd` and adding notes about _Windows XP_ and earlier support

Comment: @AmigoJack: If the text-format is not available, then `Clipboard.AsText` will be an empty string and the button will be disabled. If a picture (or any other format) is stored into the clipboard, it's right to be notified because I could have to disable my paste button. Am I missing something?

Comment: Inspecting the format is unbound to the clipboard content's size - also text can easily fill hundreds of megabytes while you happily issue `Clipboard.AsText` even multiple times (which, on top, may every time convert first). As per target system performance may be a limited resource.

Comment: @AmigoJack: You convinced me! I've updated the answer